# array is not a function in react native in sub map array

Tags: arrays, react-native

this is my code to call arrays of object

```
 {data.map((item, index ) =>
        <View>
        <Text key={index}>{item.type}</Text>

        {item.resultlist((sub,index)=>

            <Text key={index}>{sub.name}</Text>

          )}
            </View>
    )}
```

and this is my response of json array

```
 {
"status": "success",
"message": "Home page Response",
"response": [
    {
        "type": "product",
        "status": true,
        "sort_order": 0,
        "resultlist": [
            {
                "name": "Mifa F1",
                "img": "https://www.achhacart.com/image/cache/catalog/new%20thumbnails/Mifa%20A1BlacjkThumbnail-600x600.jpg",
                "type": "product",
                "product_id": 87
            },
            {
                "name": "Earphone",
                "img": "https://www.achhacart.com/image/catalog/cmsblock/hgb5.png",
                "type": "category",
                "category_id": 20
            },
            {
                "name": "Air Purifier",
                "img": "https://www.achhacart.com/image/catalog/cmsblock/air.gif",
                "type": "product",
                "product_id": 87
            },
            {
                "name": "Powerbank",
                "img": "https://www.achhacart.com/image/catalog/cmsblock/Powerbank10.jpg",
                "type": "product",
                "product_id": 87
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "middleimage",
        "status": true,
        "sort_order": 1,
        "img": "https://www.achhacart.com/image/catalog/cmsblock/Powerbank10.jpg",
        "product_id": 187
    },
    {
        "type": "product",
        "status": true,
        "sort_order": 2,
        "resultlist": [
            {
                "name": "Mifa A1 Black",
                "img": "https://www.achhacart.com/image/cache/catalog/new%20thumbnails/Mifa%20A1BlacjkThumbnail-600x600.jpg",
                "type": "product",
                "product_id": 87
            },
            {
                "name": "Earphones",
                "img": "https://www.achhacart.com/image/catalog/cmsblock/hgb5.png",
                "type": "category",
                "category_id": 20
            },
            {
                "name": "Air Purifiers",
                "img": "https://www.achhacart.com/image/catalog/cmsblock/air.gif",
                "type": "product",
                "product_id": 87
            },
            {
                "name": "Powerbanks",
                "img": "https://www.achhacart.com/image/catalog/cmsblock/Powerbank10.jpg",
                "type": "product",
                "product_id": 87
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "slider",
        "status": true,
        "sort_order": 3,
        "resultlist": [
            {
                "title": "slider1",
                "link": "",
                "image": "https://www.achhamall.com/staging-achhamall.com/image/catalog/1AA/WeChatImage_20191228151402.jpg"
            },
            {
                "title": "slider2",
                "link": "",
                "image": "https://www.achhamall.com/staging-achhamall.com/image/catalog/1accc/WeChatImage_20191231125513.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

how should i call the sub array inside the whole array function in react native i am using the map function but still the error is same 
and when i call the array object outside the array object then its render 
suggest me where i am wrong

Comment: i am storing my array data in state function   const data = this.state.achhamall;
at globally

Comment: `item.resultlist` should probably be changed to `item.resultlist.map`

Comment: now it give type-error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.resultlist.map')

Comment: Well yes, not all your items have the object `resultList` on them

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `map` by the looks of it when you are trying to iterate over `resultlist`.

`item.resultlist` -> `item.resultlist.map((sub, index) => { ... }`

It also looks like not every `item` in `data` contains a `resultlist` so maybe check if it exists also.

Comment: @AoudeshJaiswal how did you do the check?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things
1) First, Yoo have to apply map in your child array also
2) You are not returning the tag elements.

Use below code

```
{data.map((item, index ) =>
    return (
        <View>
            <Text key={index}>{item.type}</Text>
            {item.resultlist.map((sub,index)=>
       return (
                    <Text key={index}>{sub.name}</Text>
                )
            )}
        </View>
    );
)}
```